# Styling secondary (side) menu in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, submenu

To confirm, I need to edit the side menu without changing the main menu style... but do not know where I can do so - or do I need to create a new class (I made a new class in the module itself, then styled it in template but it won't change the line-height, I was only able to set the font size for some reason)
http://dev.addrenaline.com/acces/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=45&Itemid=132

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there... by adding a `left-menu` class to your module as you've done you can target any element inside the module with this selector, e.g.:

```
.left-menu p {
  /* styles apply to paragraphs inside your module only */
}
```

The reason why your `line-height` style isn't working is because you have to apply it to your *list items*, not the entire div. This should work:

```
.left-menu li {
  line-height: 155%;
}
```